# How to add an image above tableview in TableViewController - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview, uisearchcontroller

I have a tableview in a tableview controller with a search bar. I want to add an image to the top of it in such a way, that it acts like a navigation bar and doesn't move and essentially shrinks the tableview. I usually use a view controller and add an image to the top, but I can't seem to do the tableviewcontroller. I tried adding a UIView and calling the

```
tableViewHeader
```

method, however my search controller disappears and when I scroll down in the tableview, the header disappears and the tableview covers the whole page.

Is there any way of adding sort of a sticky header to the tableview in the tableviewcontroller, so that it stays there and my search controller doesn't disappear.

Comment: Please share your code. Impossible to diagnose without seeing what you've tried.

Comment: What code do you need?

Comment: Code to reproduce the problem you’re having

Comment: You want image above or below or over the Navigation Bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `UIImgaeView` in `HeaderView` of that `TableView`.
Something like that -

```
    let headerImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: Frame)

    headerImageView.image = Image

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerImageView
```

Answer (score 0):

No With `UITableViewController`  You can't add image like you can do with `UIViewController`

For now you have following options

1) Switch to UIViewController and add uitableview and whatever your view is.

2) If you are using navigation controller then add subview to navigation controlller's view

3) Add Subview directly to `UIWindow` of appdelegate

Comment: How would I add a subview?

Comment: @ArnavGUPTA         `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.addSubview(yourView)`

Comment: Could you please write this in swift 3 syntax :)